# How to run a Node app (NextJS) on gcloud from github?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I have followed these steps:

- I installed `Google Cloud Build app on Github, linked it to Cloud Build and configured it to use a certain repository (a private one)
- I set up a trigger at Cloud Build: `Push to any branch`
- the project has no app instances after deploying (App Engine -> Dashboard)

My `cloudbuild.yarml` looks like this:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args: ['app', 'deploy', '--project=project-name', '--version=$SHORT_SHA']
```

If I try to run the trigger manually: I get this error in Google Cloud:

> unable to get credentials for cloud build robot

I have also tried to set IAM roles based on [this article](https://leighmcculloch.com/posts/continuous-deployment-to-app-engine-using-google-cloud-build/) but using @cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com doesn't seem to be a valid "member" (perhaps I need two projects, one for running and one for building the app?)

**How do I fill the gaps / fixes the errors mentioned?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the error message looking for credential that has the required permission. From the [article](https://leighmcculloch.com/posts/continuous-deployment-to-app-engine-using-google-cloud-build/) that you are following, in the step #4, don't add manually the Service Account for Cloud Build. Check if you enable the **Cloud Build API** in your project, if the API is disabled try to enable. It will automatically create the Service Account for Cloud Build and look likes this:

> [PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com

Once the service account is created, go to Cloud Build  > Setting page and enable the required roles for you application.

Comment: Thanks John. Does Cloud build create a new "app" as well? It's my understanding the usual flow (with manual deploy/build) is "create app" -> "connect to server running app" -> "do stuff..."

Comment: Lots going on atm but I will try your suggestions asap :)